# Integrating over a triangle

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $\hat T$ be the triangle spanned by $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Let
$$I(r,s) = \int_{\hat T} x^r y^s d(x,y)$$
with $r,s\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$.
Prove that 
$$I(r,s) = \frac{r!s!}{(2+r+s)!}$$

To show this I rewrote the integral to 
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{-x+1} x^r y^s dy dx  = \frac{1}{s+1}\int_0^1 x^r (1-x)^{s+1}dx$$

but I don't know how to continue from this point.
How can I solve this? Or is there another way to prove the proposition?

Comment: Can we assume r and s to be integers?

Comment: If so, then I guess integration by parts would do the job.

Comment: @Ali OP started off stating that $r, s$ are non-negative integers, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trick is using integration by parts:

$$I\left[m,n\right] = \int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^{n}dx= \int_0^1 (x^m dx)(1-x)^n$$

Now using the formula$\int{v\ du}= uv-\int{u\ dv}$:

$$I\left[m,n\right]=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}(1-x)^n|_0^1+ \frac{n}{m+1} \int_0^1 x^{m+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-1}=0+\frac{n}{m+1}I\left[m+1,n-1\right]$$

Now using this formula repeatedly in our case will give us:

$$\frac{1}{s+1}I\left[r,s+1\right]=\frac{1}{r}I\left[r+1,s\right]=\frac{s}{r(r+1)}I\left[r+2,s-1\right]=\frac{s!\ r!}{(r+s+1)!}I\left[r+s+2,0\right]$$

But now,$I[r+s+2,0]$ is simply $\frac{1}{r+s+2}$, ergo:

$$I=\frac{s!\ r!}{(r+s+2)!}$$

Comment: I see what you did there but shouldn't it be $I(m,n) = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n dx$? I tried to do a similar calculation but had trouble as the factor $1/n$ and $1/(s+1)$ respectively always got in the way

Comment: okay, having done further calculations I could figure it all out, thank you!

Comment: @dinosaur You are welcome :)

Comment: @Ali $\huge\color{green}{✓}^\color{red}{+}$

Answer (score 3):

The integral you arrived at is an example of the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). It is easily evaluated for natural numbers $ x, y $ by the method Ali posted.