# Integrating $\int_{-1}^{1}(1+x)^m(1-x)^ndx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Stimulated by the physics background of *path integral*, I want to know how to calculate this integral
$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1+x)^m(1-x)^ndx,$$
where $m$, $n$ are positive integers. I'm struggling with it.

Different kinds of approaches are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial integration. Repeat until you get something _simple_.

Comment: Closely related(possible duplicate) to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404980/integrating-over-a-triangle/405011#405011)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let denote
$$I(n,m)=\int_{-1}^{1}(1+x)^m(1-x)^ndx$$
so by integration by parts we find
$$I(n,m)=\frac{m}{n+1}I(n+1,m-1)$$
and then by induction

$$I(n,m)=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}I(n+m,0)=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}2^{n+m+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** use Newton's binomial formula to develop both factors and get a linear combination of integrals of the the form
$$\int_{[-1,1]} x^k x^\ell dx$$
which you can integrate more easily (see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5Ek+x%5En%2C+for+x+from+-1+to+1) to check your result).

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $1+x=2u$ we obtain
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}(1+x)^m(1-x)^n dx=2^{m+n+1}\int_0^1 u^m (1-u)^n du
$$
Here the integral is the (well-known) [Beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) which can be calculated e.g. integrating by parts. The (final) result is 
$$
2^{m+n+1}\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(m+n+2)}=2^{m+n+1}\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}.
$$